# laptop not booting to 20.04 usb made with rufus

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, live-usb

Made bootable usb using rufus, new asus tuf a15
the bios is uefi without cms
When selecting usb from boot menu theres a black screen for a second goes back to boot menu. How to boot into the usb.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: Most of the reasons a boot drive may fail to boot can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot

Answer (score 1):

TUF A15 FX506IV user here. I had the same issue with installing windows, as I removed the original M.2 drive and replaced it with a blank drive.
I tried a long time to get it to boot, then went and made myself some food. When I came back, it had somehow magically discovered the USB stick and started windows install.
I have since been unable to boot from USB again.

Something is funky with USB boot on FX506. Replacing rufus with balena makes no difference. The BIOS sees the USB stick, but refuses to show it as a boot option. Disabling secure boot and fast boot does no difference. Additionally there's no CSM option in the BIOS.

Comment: Yeah same situation here, no csm option in bios. No idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

Asus tuf fx505dy user here. You should download [this](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) and flash the usb again. I had the same problem.

Comment: Using this usb not showing up on boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer is unwilling (or unable) to boot from any external media, but you have acceess to a more willing computer, the following methods are possible.

### Method 1

- Get an adapter or external box for your internal drive. There are plenty of such adpaters with an USB to SATA interface, but I have seen some adapters with USB to M.2  interface too.
- Boot the more willing computer into an Ubuntu live drive
- Install Ubuntu into the drive connected via that adapter
- [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)
- Move the drive (now with an installed Ubuntu system) into the unwilling oomputer.

### Method 2

- Get an adapter or external box for your internal drive. There are plenty of such adpaters with an USB to SATA interface, but I have seen some adapters with USB to M.2  interface too.
- You can use an **image file of an installed system** to install Ubuntu via the adapter in the more willing computer.
- In this case you need not boot into a live Ubuntu drive, and you need not run the installer, only do the standard tasks to extract from the compression, clone to the drive in the adpater and fix the GPT partition table.
- [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)
- Move the drive (now with an installed Ubuntu system) into the unwilling oomputer.